# apache jena imports doesn't work with java

Tags: sparql, jena

have a problem with the apache jena imports to create a java project, when I tried to import the libraries, imports said "can't find symbol" o "can't resolve", I don't know what to do, please heeeelp!!

Psdt: I'm using 4.5.0 version of apache jena

[ERROR HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNEQT.png)

Comment: that is not enough information. Do you have all the necessary Jena dependencies in the classpath? Note, it is highly recommended to use a Maven build system

Comment: Yeah, i downloaded all the jar files from https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi and i added to java libraries, also i tried with maven but is the same error!!

Comment: please post your Maven POM file - and also, is your IDE capable of recognizing a Maven project? Does `mvn compile` work from command line?